# go back from Gnome 3.8 to Gnome 3.6 in LUBUNTU 13.04

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I had Lubuntu 12.04 and wanted to try Gnome Shell. When I added the Gnome3 PPA, that got me on 3.4. I wanted to use 3.6 though and follow new releases from there, but from what I gathered about this topic essentially it looked like I had to upgrade the distro to do so. Now I'm on Lubuntu 13.04, and, with the Gnome3 ppa enabled, I guess the next apt-get update automatically took me to 3.8.
Now 3.8 at least isn't officially beta anymore, but still too unrounded and crashes way too often for my taste, so I'd like to give it a few more months and stay with 3.6 in the meantime, is that possible?
thanks, Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143894

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome
```

That will remove the Gnome ppa entirely if you need it to. If not, my suggestion (if you were lucky/smart enough to partition home separately from root) is to just install Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 if you're willing to go full bore into Gnome.
I've been using it and aside from an issue with the workspace switching, it has been buttery smooth. I'm actually impressed as last time I used it it was twitchy, would lock up on lock screen, and had a few crashes of the shell.

And after the fact, if you want you can always add the Gnome PPA again and go for 3.8.

Edit- Try this- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gnome-3-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-gnome

Basically, purge the Gnome PPA, update your repo list, remove the Gnome shell entirely (should leave you with just Lubuntu interface) and then go back and reinstall Gnome shell. Gnome will then be picked up from the official Ubuntu repositories and install 3.6 (and all other Gnome required libs, apps, etc.)

Comment: ...and removing the Gnome ppa will hardly give me Gnome 3.6, will it? By now I assume there is actually no way to do it :-( I have been hoping though for Gnome 3.6 to be so well implemented in UG as to amount to the smoothness you're describing

Comment: See above- edited it and it should help you. I would advise in the future to install root and home to separate partitions so your personal stuff can be safe and your OS can be upgraded without issue.

Comment: Before I try this: customizing Gnome to what I want it to do is still a great deal of work, and I'd hate to lose the layout I have now. Is it possible to backup just the Gnome Shell setup I have now and restore it after in Gnome 3.6? Or maybe just print a list of extensions and all the customizations I used including themes? Otherwise, what would happen if I *only* purged the Gnome3 ppa? That means my current Gnome Shell would never be touched by updates, yes?

Answer (score -1):

The following article explains a generic procedure to revert/downgrade to the standard repository versions of packages or even a subsystem if your system becomes unstable after installing packages from testing PPAs:

http://oldpapyrus.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/rescue-ubuntu-from-unstable-ppa-issues/

Comment: Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. And always quote the most relevant part. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)